# Как лучше читать литературу по программированию?

Tags: c#, книги

Вот такой вопрос: есть ли смысл читать литературу по программированию без практики? Прочитать за неделю книгу, например *Эндрю Троелсен "Язык Программирования С# 5.0 и Платформа Net 4.5"* и за всю неделю не притронуться к практике за компьютером.

Останется ли что-то в голове после прочтения, или без повторения примеров сразу после прочтения всё забудется? 
Вопрос немного странен и, возможно, тупой, но я новичок, поэтому и интересуюсь, не будет ли это пустой тратой времени.
Как я уже говорил, я задал тупой вопрос. Поэтому вопрос закрыт!

Comment: Сколько людей столько и мнений будет, у всех же по разному материал усваивается.

Comment: Если вы новичок и боитесь без практики, может быть стоит почитать книжки с упражнениями? [Здесь](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/416585/5079) первая книжка с упражнениями, про остальные не знаю

Comment: Думаю, это как секс. Вы можете читать книги сколько угодно, но практику ничто не заменит.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если Вы прочитаете Эндрю Троелсена "Язык Программирования С# 5.0 и Платформа Net 4.5" без практики, то Вы не программист ибо множество кода вызовет у Вас вопросы и вам просто необходимо будет его писать и пробовать то чего в книге нету (примеры кода имеется в виду). Я сам сейчас .NET dev и помню что на полноценное прочтение этой книги у меня ушло больше месяца, так как я много времени тратил на разбор примеров кода, и дописывал свое что то. Проводил аналогии. Анализировал что и почему так. Потом прочитал Рихтера и большинство вопросов решились сами собой.

**Вывод:** практика нужна. Тем более новичку.

Answer (score 4):

Если вы не новичок в программировании.
То все будет зависеть от литературы.
Без практики можно читать книги, но не учебники. Если в книге идет речь не о примерах и сделай это сделай то, а описываться будут методики, технологии, особенности, архитектуры и сама книги будет в основном состоять из рассуждений автора, то можно.

Была у меня такая книга, да сейчас название не вспомню, буду дома постараюсь найти, отпишусь.

К таким книгам можно отнести "[Эффективное использование С++](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321334876)".

Answer (score 3):

Нет, смысла так ее читать нет ни малейшего. Книги по программированию - это не художественная литература. Теория без практики пользы не принесет наверняка (практика без теории может и принесет, но тоже ничего хорошего не сулит)
Что же насчет Троелсена, то у него в книге множество примеров кода, которые и предполагается разбирать, выполнять и отлаживать, так что проблемы в этом не вижу

Answer (score 3):

Читать книгу конечно хорошо, но без постоянной практики хотя бы 1 час каждый день, это пустая трата времени. Проходите онлайн уроки и параллельно читайте литературу- это укрепит ваши практические навыки и теоретические сведения.

Answer (score 3):

Лично я нахожу наиболее эффективным сначала читать большой объем (однако не всю книгу, а скажем главу или раздел) информации, а потом за компом опробовать полученные знания - скажем часов 5 посидеть и поиграться с кодом. Просто если читать и сразу писать все примеры, то времени это займет раз в 5 больше, в толку большого не будет. 
Мой совет уместен, если вы умеете программировать и просто изучаете новый язык. Если же учите программирование, то тут все иначе - надо все скурпулезнее делать (советую Лафоре ООП C++  для таких целей).
Ну и вообще, нужно самому попробовать разные способы. Главное потом, когда писать начнете помнить, где взять быстро инфу - в этом чтение книг помогает.

Answer (score 3):

Как вы сказали, книгу по программированию из 1312 страниц за неделю?:) 
Смысл есть, как мне кажется, если потом вернуться к началу и начать работать с книгой, выполняя примеры и практикуясь. После первого прочтения у вас уже будет что-то в голове, и дальнейшее изучение пойдет легче и быстрее. Сталкивался с подобным, когда три недели лежал в больнице и изучал книгу по ассемблеру, а ноутбуки тогда еще не были такими доступными. Упражнения выполнялись ручкой на бумаге.